# Fatal error: Class 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker' not found in /

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am working on a Wordpress theme and I continue to get a fatal error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/header.php on line 35
```

Can someone please help me identify what changes I need to make in which file? I have been following a youtube video step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-AGjdMrtdA

**Function.php**

```
<?php
      // Register Nav Walker class_alias
    require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');


        // Theme Support
        function wpb_theme_setup(){
            // Nav Menus
            register_nav_menus(array(
            'primary' => __('Primary Menu', 'wpbootstrap')
            ));
        }

         add_action('after_setup_theme','wpb_theme_setup');
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo("charset"); ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description') ?>">
    <title>
        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | 
        <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(); ?>
    </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php wp_head (); ?>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blog-masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="blog-nav">
           <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="blog-header">
        <h1 class="blog-title"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
        <p class="lead blog-description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
      </div>
```

**wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * WP Bootstrap Navwalker
 *
 * @package WP-Bootstrap-Navwalker
 */

/**
 * Class Name: WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker
 * Plugin Name: WP Bootstrap Navwalker
 * Plugin URI:  https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker
 * Description: A custom WordPress nav walker class to implement the Bootstrap 3 navigation style in a custom theme using the WordPress built in menu manager.
 * Author: Edward McIntyre - @twittem, WP Bootstrap
 * Version: 2.0.5
 * Author URI: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap
 * GitHub Plugin URI: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker
 * GitHub Branch: master
 * License: GPL-3.0+
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt
 */

/* Check if Class Exists. */
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker' ) ) {
    /**
     * WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker class.
     *
     * @extends Walker_Nav_Menu
     */
    class WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

        /**
         * Start Level.
         *
         * @see Walker::start_lvl()
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @access public
         * @param mixed $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @param int   $depth (default: 0) Depth of page. Used for padding.
         * @param array $args (default: array()) Arguments.
         * @return void
         */
        public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul role=\"menu\" class=\" dropdown-menu\" >\n";
        }

        /**
         * Start El.
         *
         * @see Walker::start_el()
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @access public
         * @param mixed $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @param mixed $item Menu item data object.
         * @param int   $depth (default: 0) Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param array $args (default: array()) Arguments.
         * @param int   $id (default: 0) Menu item ID.
         * @return void
         */
        public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

            /**
             * Dividers, Headers or Disabled
             * =============================
             * Determine whether the item is a Divider, Header, Disabled or regular
             * menu item. To prevent errors we use the strcasecmp() function to so a
             * comparison that is not case sensitive. The strcasecmp() function returns
             * a 0 if the strings are equal.
             */
            if ( 0 === strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'divider' ) && 1 === $depth ) {
                $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
            } elseif ( 0 === strcasecmp( $item->title, 'divider' ) && 1 === $depth ) {
                $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="divider">';
            } elseif ( 0 === strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'dropdown-header' ) && 1 === $depth ) {
                $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">' . esc_attr( $item->title );
            } elseif ( 0 === strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'disabled' ) ) {
                $output .= $indent . '<li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a href="#">' . esc_attr( $item->title ) . '</a>';
            } else {
                $value = '';
                $class_names = $value;
                $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
                $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
                $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
                if ( $args->has_children ) {
                    $class_names .= ' dropdown';
                }
                if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes, true ) ) {
                    $class_names .= ' active';
                }
                $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
                $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args );
                $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
                $output .= $indent . '<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"' . $id . $value . $class_names . '>';
                $atts = array();

                if ( empty( $item->attr_title ) ) {
                    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title )   ? strip_tags( $item->title ) : '';
                } else {
                    $atts['title'] = $item->attr_title;
                }

                $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
                $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )    ? $item->xfn    : '';
                // If item has_children add atts to a.
                if ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) {
                    $atts['href']           = '#';
                    $atts['data-toggle']    = 'dropdown';
                    $atts['class']          = 'dropdown-toggle';
                    $atts['aria-haspopup']  = 'true';
                } else {
                    $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
                }
                $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );
                $attributes = '';
                foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                        $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                        $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
                    }
                }
                $item_output = $args->before;

                /*
                 * Glyphicons/Font-Awesome
                 * ===========
                 * Since the the menu item is NOT a Divider or Header we check the see
                 * if there is a value in the attr_title property. If the attr_title
                 * property is NOT null we apply it as the class name for the glyphicon.
                 */
                if ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ) {
                    $pos = strpos( esc_attr( $item->attr_title ), 'glyphicon' );
                    if ( false !== $pos ) {
                        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><span class="glyphicon ' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;';
                    } else {
                        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><i class="fa ' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;';
                    }
                } else {
                    $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
                }
                $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
                $item_output .= ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? ' <span class="caret"></span></a>' : '</a>';
                $item_output .= $args->after;
                $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
            } // End if().
        }

        /**
         * Traverse elements to create list from elements.
         *
         * Display one element if the element doesn't have any children otherwise,
         * display the element and its children. Will only traverse up to the max
         * depth and no ignore elements under that depth.
         *
         * This method shouldn't be called directly, use the walk() method instead.
         *
         * @see Walker::start_el()
         * @since 2.5.0
         *
         * @access public
         * @param mixed $element Data object.
         * @param mixed $children_elements List of elements to continue traversing.
         * @param mixed $max_depth Max depth to traverse.
         * @param mixed $depth Depth of current element.
         * @param mixed $args Arguments.
         * @param mixed $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
         * @return null Null on failure with no changes to parameters.
         */
        public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, &$output ) {
            if ( ! $element ) {
                return; }
            $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
            // Display this element.
            if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
                $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[ $element->$id_field ] ); }
            parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
        }

        /**
         * Menu Fallback
         * =============
         * If this function is assigned to the wp_nav_menu's fallback_cb variable
         * and a menu has not been assigned to the theme location in the WordPress
         * menu manager the function with display nothing to a non-logged in user,
         * and will add a link to the WordPress menu manager if logged in as an admin.
         *
         * @param array $args passed from the wp_nav_menu function.
         */
        public static function fallback( $args ) {
            if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {

                /* Get Arguments. */
                $container = $args['container'];
                $container_id = $args['container_id'];
                $container_class = $args['container_class'];
                $menu_class = $args['menu_class'];
                $menu_id = $args['menu_id'];

                if ( $container ) {
                    echo '<' . esc_attr( $container );
                    if ( $container_id ) {
                        echo ' id="' . esc_attr( $container_id ) . '"';
                    }
                    if ( $container_class ) {
                        echo ' class="' . sanitize_html_class( $container_class ) . '"'; }
                    echo '>';
                }
                echo '<ul';
                if ( $menu_id ) {
                    echo ' id="' . esc_attr( $menu_id ) . '"'; }
                if ( $menu_class ) {
                    echo ' class="' . esc_attr( $menu_class ) . '"'; }
                echo '>';
                echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) . '" title="">' . esc_attr( 'Add a menu', '' ) . '</a></li>';
                echo '</ul>';
                if ( $container ) {
                    echo '</' . esc_attr( $container ) . '>'; }
            }
        }
    }
} // End if().
```

Comment: Dup of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248895/wp-bootstrap-navwalker-fatal-error ?

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to create the `WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker.php` and include it. Put the following line into `functions.php:` file `require_once(get_template_directory() . "/inc/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php");`

This assumes that the file is in an `/inc` folder. If the site now runs without error, the final step is to add the `'walker' => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()` line to the `wp_nav_menu` call.

**More info:** https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Try to update your code here:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'              => 'primary',
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
        ));
?>
```

#### I hope it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code.
Actually, you have done the mistake while saving the **functions.php**. The mistake is instead of "**functions.php**" you have saved it as "**function.php**". This is why the fatal error is appearing.