# Fatal error: Class 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker' not found in

Tags: php, wordpress

I was working on a website and somehow broke it. I did not create this website but was working to update the SEO and a few minor items. This is a bit out of my depth to be honest. 
I'm not sure what I did but now I'm getting:

`Fatal error: Class 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker' not found in /home/content/92/11969592/html/wp-content/themes/kim/header.php on line 82`

I've searched everything I can find on here and on every website I can find, but I can't seem to fix it. This is the code after trying to make changes according to this topic `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445283/fatal-error-class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker-not-found-in`

Can anyone help me?
Thank you for any help you can provide!

functions.php

```
<?php
/**

 * For more information on hooks, actions, and filters,
 * {@link https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/}
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */

/**
 * Twenty Sixteen only works in WordPress 4.4 or later.
 */
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '4.4-alpha', '<' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/back-compat.php';
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentysixteen_setup' ) ) :

     *
     * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
     */
    function twentysixteen_setup() {

        load_theme_textdomain( 'twentysixteen' );

        // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        add_theme_support(
            'custom-logo',
            array(
                'height'      => 240,
                'width'       => 240,
                'flex-height' => true,
            )
        );


        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 1200, 9999 );

        // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.
        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
                'social'  => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
            )
        );

        /*
         * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
         * to output valid HTML5.
         */
        add_theme_support(
            'html5',
            array(
                'search-form',
                'comment-form',
                'comment-list',
                'gallery',
                'caption',
                'script',
                'style',
            )
        );

        /*
         * Enable support for Post Formats.
         *
         * See: https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-formats/
         */
        add_theme_support(
            'post-formats',
            array(
                'aside',
                'image',
                'video',
                'quote',
                'link',
                'gallery',
                'status',
                'audio',
                'chat',
            )
        );

        /*
         * This theme styles the visual editor to resemble the theme style,
         * specifically font, colors, icons, and column width.
         */
        add_editor_style( array( 'css/editor-style.css', twentysixteen_fonts_url() ) );

        // Load regular editor styles into the new block-based editor.
        add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );

        // Load default block styles.
        add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );

        // Add support for responsive embeds.
        add_theme_support( 'responsive-embeds' );

        // Add support for custom color scheme.
        add_theme_support(
            'editor-color-palette',
            array(
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Dark Gray', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'dark-gray',
                    'color' => '#1a1a1a',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Medium Gray', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'medium-gray',
                    'color' => '#686868',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Light Gray', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'light-gray',
                    'color' => '#e5e5e5',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'White', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'white',
                    'color' => '#fff',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Blue Gray', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'blue-gray',
                    'color' => '#4d545c',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Bright Blue', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'bright-blue',
                    'color' => '#007acc',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Light Blue', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'light-blue',
                    'color' => '#9adffd',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Dark Brown', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'dark-brown',
                    'color' => '#402b30',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Medium Brown', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'medium-brown',
                    'color' => '#774e24',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Dark Red', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'dark-red',
                    'color' => '#640c1f',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Bright Red', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'bright-red',
                    'color' => '#ff675f',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'  => __( 'Yellow', 'twentysixteen' ),
                    'slug'  => 'yellow',
                    'color' => '#ffef8e',
                ),
            )
        );


                 add_action('after_setup_theme','wpb_theme_setup');
        // Indicate widget sidebars can use selective refresh in the Customizer.
        add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );
    }
endif; // twentysixteen_setup()
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentysixteen_setup' );

/**
 * Sets the content width in pixels, based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 *
 * Priority 0 to make it available to lower priority callbacks.
 *
 * @global int $content_width
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_content_width', 840 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentysixteen_content_width', 0 );

/**
 * Add preconnect for Google Fonts.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.6
 *
 * @param array  $urls           URLs to print for resource hints.
 * @param string $relation_type  The relation type the URLs are printed.
 * @return array $urls           URLs to print for resource hints.
 */
function twentysixteen_resource_hints( $urls, $relation_type ) {
    if ( wp_style_is( 'twentysixteen-fonts', 'queue' ) && 'preconnect' === $relation_type ) {
        $urls[] = array(
            'href' => 'https://fonts.gstatic.com',
            'crossorigin',
        );
    }

    return $urls;
}
add_filter( 'wp_resource_hints', 'twentysixteen_resource_hints', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Registers a widget area.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => __( 'Content Bottom 1', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
            'description'   => __( 'Appears at the bottom of the content on posts and pages.', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => __( 'Content Bottom 2', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
            'description'   => __( 'Appears at the bottom of the content on posts and pages.', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentysixteen_widgets_init' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentysixteen_fonts_url' ) ) :
    /**
     * Register Google fonts for Twenty Sixteen.
     *
     * Create your own twentysixteen_fonts_url() function to override in a child theme.
     *
     * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
     *
     * @return string Google fonts URL for the theme.
     */
    function twentysixteen_fonts_url() {
        $fonts_url = '';
        $fonts     = array();
        $subsets   = 'latin,latin-ext';

        /*
         * translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported
         * by Merriweather, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate into your own language.
         */
        if ( 'off' !== _x( 'on', 'Merriweather font: on or off', 'twentysixteen' ) ) {
            $fonts[] = 'Merriweather:400,700,900,400italic,700italic,900italic';
        }

        /*
         * translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported
         * by Montserrat, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate into your own language.
         */
        if ( 'off' !== _x( 'on', 'Montserrat font: on or off', 'twentysixteen' ) ) {
            $fonts[] = 'Montserrat:400,700';
        }

        /*
         * translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported
         * by Inconsolata, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate into your own language.
         */
        if ( 'off' !== _x( 'on', 'Inconsolata font: on or off', 'twentysixteen' ) ) {
            $fonts[] = 'Inconsolata:400';
        }

        if ( $fonts ) {
            $fonts_url = add_query_arg(
                array(
                    'family'  => urlencode( implode( '|', $fonts ) ),
                    'subset'  => urlencode( $subsets ),
                    'display' => urlencode( 'fallback' ),
                ),
                'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css'
            );
        }

        return $fonts_url;
    }
endif;

/**
 * Handles JavaScript detection.
 *
 * Adds a `js` class to the root `<html>` element when JavaScript is detected.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_javascript_detection() {
    echo "<script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'twentysixteen_javascript_detection', 0 );

/**
 * Enqueues scripts and styles.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_scripts() {
    // Add custom fonts, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-fonts', twentysixteen_fonts_url(), array(), null );

    // Add Genericons, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/genericons/genericons.css', array(), '3.4.1' );

    // Theme stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '20190507' );

    // Theme block stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-block-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/blocks.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20190102' );

    // Load the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20170530' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 10' );

    // Load the Internet Explorer 8 specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie8', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie8.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20170530' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie8', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    // Load the Internet Explorer 7 specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-ie7', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie7.css', array( 'twentysixteen-style' ), '20170530' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentysixteen-ie7', 'conditional', 'lt IE 8' );

    // Load the html5 shiv.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-html5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5.js', array(), '3.7.3' );
    wp_script_add_data( 'twentysixteen-html5', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20170530', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    if ( is_singular() && wp_attachment_is_image() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-keyboard-image-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/keyboard-image-navigation.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20170530' );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20181217', true );

    wp_localize_script(
        'twentysixteen-script',
        'screenReaderText',
        array(
            'expand'   => __( 'expand child menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'collapse' => __( 'collapse child menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentysixteen_scripts' );

/**
 * Enqueue styles for the block-based editor.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.6
 */
function twentysixteen_block_editor_styles() {
    // Block styles.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-block-editor-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/editor-blocks.css', array(), '20190102' );
    // Add custom fonts.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentysixteen-fonts', twentysixteen_fonts_url(), array(), null );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'twentysixteen_block_editor_styles' );

/**
 * Adds custom classes to the array of body classes.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param array $classes Classes for the body element.
 * @return array (Maybe) filtered body classes.
 */
function twentysixteen_body_classes( $classes ) {
    // Adds a class of custom-background-image to sites with a custom background image.
    if ( get_background_image() ) {
        $classes[] = 'custom-background-image';
    }

    // Adds a class of group-blog to sites with more than 1 published author.
    if ( is_multi_author() ) {
        $classes[] = 'group-blog';
    }

    // Adds a class of no-sidebar to sites without active sidebar.
    if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'no-sidebar';
    }

    // Adds a class of hfeed to non-singular pages.
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        $classes[] = 'hfeed';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'twentysixteen_body_classes' );

/**
 * Converts a HEX value to RGB.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param string $color The original color, in 3- or 6-digit hexadecimal form.
 * @return array Array containing RGB (red, green, and blue) values for the given
 *               HEX code, empty array otherwise.
 */
function twentysixteen_hex2rgb( $color ) {
    $color = trim( $color, '#' );

    if ( strlen( $color ) === 3 ) {
        $r = hexdec( substr( $color, 0, 1 ) . substr( $color, 0, 1 ) );
        $g = hexdec( substr( $color, 1, 1 ) . substr( $color, 1, 1 ) );
        $b = hexdec( substr( $color, 2, 1 ) . substr( $color, 2, 1 ) );
    } elseif ( strlen( $color ) === 6 ) {
        $r = hexdec( substr( $color, 0, 2 ) );
        $g = hexdec( substr( $color, 2, 2 ) );
        $b = hexdec( substr( $color, 4, 2 ) );
    } else {
        return array();
    }

    return array(
        'red'   => $r,
        'green' => $g,
        'blue'  => $b,
    );
}

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';


/**
 * Add custom image sizes attribute to enhance responsive image functionality
 * for content images
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param string $sizes A source size value for use in a 'sizes' attribute.
 * @param array  $size  Image size. Accepts an array of width and height
 *                      values in pixels (in that order).
 * @return string A source size value for use in a content image 'sizes' attribute.
 */
function twentysixteen_content_image_sizes_attr( $sizes, $size ) {
    $width = $size[0];

    if ( 840 <= $width ) {
        $sizes = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 1362px) 62vw, 840px';
    }

    if ( 'page' === get_post_type() ) {
        if ( 840 > $width ) {
            $sizes = '(max-width: ' . $width . 'px) 85vw, ' . $width . 'px';
        }
    } else {
        if ( 840 > $width && 600 <= $width ) {
            $sizes = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 61vw, (max-width: 1362px) 45vw, 600px';
        } elseif ( 600 > $width ) {
            $sizes = '(max-width: ' . $width . 'px) 85vw, ' . $width . 'px';
        }
    }

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_sizes', 'twentysixteen_content_image_sizes_attr', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add custom image sizes attribute to enhance responsive image functionality
 * for post thumbnails
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param array $attr Attributes for the image markup.
 * @param int   $attachment Image attachment ID.
 * @param array $size Registered image size or flat array of height and width dimensions.
 * @return array The filtered attributes for the image markup.
 */
function twentysixteen_post_thumbnail_sizes_attr( $attr, $attachment, $size ) {
    if ( 'post-thumbnail' === $size ) {
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
            $attr['sizes'] = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 60vw, (max-width: 1362px) 62vw, 840px';
        } else {
            $attr['sizes'] = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 1362px) 88vw, 1200px';
        }
    }
    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'twentysixteen_post_thumbnail_sizes_attr', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Modifies tag cloud widget arguments to display all tags in the same font size
 * and use list format for better accessibility.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.1
 *
 * @param array $args Arguments for tag cloud widget.
 * @return array The filtered arguments for tag cloud widget.
 */
function twentysixteen_widget_tag_cloud_args( $args ) {
    $args['largest']  = 1;
    $args['smallest'] = 1;
    $args['unit']     = 'em';
    $args['format']   = 'list';

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'twentysixteen_widget_tag_cloud_args' );
```

header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the header
 *
 * Displays all of the head element and everything up until the "site-content" div.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js" style="margin-top: 0px !important;">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title><?php if(is_home()) { echo bloginfo("name"); echo " | "; echo bloginfo("description"); } else { echo wp_title(" | ", false, right); echo bloginfo("name"); } ?></title>

    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php if ( is_singular() && pings_open( get_queried_object() ) ) : ?>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <style>
    .search .blog_page_content .b-title h3 a{color: #75c3d5;font-family: "futura-mediumregular";font-size: 35px;letter-spacing: 2px;}
    .search .blog_page_content .b-title h3 a:hover{text-decoration: none;color:#351561;}
    .search .blog_page_content .b-title h3{clear: unset; margin-top: 0px;}
    </style>

    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-44104510-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.social_menu_footer a, .social-slider-icons a, .social-icons a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('href') == 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/kimberley-cochrane-ma-diptirp-cec-capt-079a3b1?trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile') {
            $(this).attr('href', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/kimberley-cochrane-registered-psychotherapist-079a3b1/');
        }
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

 <div class="<?php if(get_field('banner')) { echo "banner"; } else {echo "no-banner";}?>">

        <header>
            <div class="header-main navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="logo text-center">
                                    <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/logo.png';?>" alt="Kim Cochrane" title="Kim Cochrane" /></a>
                                </div>
                                                <?php
                                                            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                                                'menu'              => 'primary',
                                                                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                                                                'depth'             => 2,
                                                                'container'         => 'div',
                                                                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                                                                'container_id'      => 'navbar',
                                                                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                                                                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                                                                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                                                            );
                                                        ?>      

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="desktop-menu">
                                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

                                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">
                                        </div>



                                </nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div id="menu2"></div>


            <?php

            $classes = get_body_class();

            if(is_front_page()) { ?>

                <div class="header-slider">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=25]"); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="social-slider-icons">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('social_icon_widget');?>
                </div>

            <?php }  elseif(is_singular( 'post' ) || is_singular( 'event' ) || is_search()) {

                 if(get_field('banner')) {  ?>

                    <div class="banner-section">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_field('banner');?>"  />

                    </div>
                    <div class="social-slider-icons">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('social_icon_widget');?>
                    </div>

            <?php }  } elseif(is_tax( 'event-categories' )) {

                   if(get_field('banner')) {  ?>

                    <div class="banner-section">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_field('banner');?>"  />
                             <div class="banner-text">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-11">
                                            <h1><?php echo single_cat_title();?></h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="social-slider-icons">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('social_icon_widget');?>
                    </div>

            <?php } } else { ?>

            <?php if(get_field('banner')) {  ?>

                    <div class="banner-section">

                            <img src="<?php echo get_field('banner');?>"  />
                            <div class="banner-text">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-11">
                                            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                                                <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>

                                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="social-slider-icons">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('social_icon_widget');?>
                    </div>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php } ?>
</header>
```

Comment: I'm willing to pay for a developer to fix this.. I've been working on it all day and am desperate. I can't figure it out. Please please please help me!

Comment: It's practically impossible for us to help when we don't know what you changed in the first place. What changes did you make before this error started to appear? If you are using the TwentySixteen theme, why not just reinstall it? (I presume you didn't make changes directly in the default theme files, because you should never do that). And in future test your changes on a development server before going near a live site, and even then always, always, *always* make a full backup before making changes.

Answer (score 0):

in /functions.php check if this lines of code are there otherwise add them

```
 /**
     * Register Custom Navigation Walker
     */
    function register_navwalker(){
        require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );
```

and then in /header check if this line of code are then if not add them

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
    'depth'           => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
    'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
) );
```